# how to add an active user feature in chat flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, chat

Hello everybody I am making a real time chat app based on flutter. I am using Firebase as backend of my app and the sample texting is working awesome. But I want to add an active feature for the chat, like when user is active, on the app for the other user he had an early conversation with him, he is showing that he is currently active, and a green light shows up like in messenger or viber or what app. Can I do it with flutter and firebase?

Comment: the answer is obviously: Yes, you can do it with just flutter and firebase....

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is what's known as a presence system, which can be implemented on Firebase's Realtime Database by combining its `.info/connected` node and its `onDisconnect` handlers. For full details see the Firebase documentation on [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence). The link is for Android, but the same functionality is available in the Flutter library.

If you're using Cloud Firestore, such functionality isn't available directly in the product, but you can [integrate Realtime Database and Firestore to build a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Comment: can i check it for other users while iam sing in an a specific user

Comment: because i need to ckeck other users than the user already singed in to say if they are connected or not

Comment: If you check the documentation I linked, it shows how to build such a presence system.